# Segregate SSH Access for Multiple Repositories in One Account

Tags: github

I would need to give access to our three git hub repositories, segregating them for working group. Each working group should be enabled to only see and operate on its own one.

I enabled the SSH pair key access method for our Company Account, going into the Company Account Settings and adding the Public Key in the SSH and GPG Keys Section. It properly works.

However, my doubt here is the following:

If I give this private key to the working groups, they would see all three repositories, while I would need to assign a different private key for each one of the repositories and working groups.

I was not able to find a section to abilitate the feature at a repository level.

Anyone who can help on this?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The typical way to do this is to grant access to those repositories based on a team.  If your company account is an organization, then you can create teams and assign each member to an appropriate team.  Then, you can grant access to each repository in its settings to an appropriate set of teams.

If your company account is an individual account, that's not ideal.  You can add some contributors to each individual repository in the settings to allow them access.  You should probably convert this company account to an organization instead.

Once you've done that, then users should use their own SSH keys or personal access tokens to access the repository.  You shouldn't need to give any organizational-level keys to users.